# Logarithm differentiation when y = 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=(x-2)^5$

Solution 1: chain rule
$y'=5(x-2)^4 \frac{d}{dx}(x-2)=5(x-2)^4$

Solution 2: logarithm differentiation
$|y|=|(x-2)^5|$
$ln|y|=5ln|x-2|$ $(x\neq2)$
$y'/y=\frac{5}{x-2}$
$y' = (x-2)^5\frac{5}{x-2}=5(x-2)^4$

In solution 2, $x\neq2$ is required because of $ln|x-2|$ but not in solution 1.
And in fact, $y$ is differentiable at 2. What is incorrect in solution 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you took the log, you restricted the domain of the equation to $x\ne 2$. You're right that $x\ne 2$ is required after that, but that doesn't mean it is necessary for the original equation to work. That domain restriction was something you added when you decided to $\operatorname{ln}$ the equation, which didn't originally have an $\operatorname{ln}$ in it.

Comment: Then how about this? $xe^{xy}=y+\sin^2x$, then find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=0$ After applying logarithmic differentiation, we can obtain $\frac{1}{x}+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin2x}{y+\sin^2x}$ but we can't get $y'$ at $x=0$ from this equation

Comment: Not using logarithmic differentiation, we can obtain $e^{xy}+xe^{xy}\left[y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right]=\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin\left(2x\right)$ so we get $y'$ at $x=0$ is $1$

Comment: Again, if you're logging you are imposing a restriction on the domain. At $x=0$, the left hand side of your equation is $0$, so you wouldn't be able to log it. That means that if you do log it, you assume that $x\ne 0$.

Comment: Similarily, In original problem($y=(x-2)^5$), I think we can't get $y'$ at $x=2$ with logarithmic diffrentiation so we need different solution(like solution 1).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's not that the log method is leading you to any false statements. It just isn't solving the problem.